# Optimum Cutting of Rod with Length n into any of 3 possibly 4 sizes

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am not sure if I am in the correct area on stack - so my apologies first ..

I need to know how I can calculate all possible combinations (for 3 different fixed lengths) that can fit into a Rod of n length.

So for example if I have 3 fixed lengths of 8, 10, 12 and a Rod of variable Length n say 50'; I want to know all the possible cuts that I can make.

Comment: You want to know if `(a + b + c) <= n` ?

Comment: What is the expected output for these values (8-10-12 and 50)?

Comment: By optimum, do you mean (a * 8 + b * 10 + c *12) is as close as possible to 50? (for instance a = 0, b = 5 and c = 0 is one of the best solutions)

Comment: @vc74 Yes as close as possible to n length in this case 50 other case it might be 33 or 27 or some other variant .

Comment: It is just counting in Mod 3. So if you let 0 = 8 ft, 1 = 10 ft, 2 = 12ft.  Then count 0,1,2,10,11,12,100,101,102,110,111,112  where 112 is two 10ft sections and one 12ft section. The largest number you would get is six 8ft sections which is 000000.

Comment: @CaptainWibble Yes all possible solutions for length n , to the closest length of n. So for example while 10 is less than 50 it is not a solution - 5*10 is as well as one 12, one 8 and three 10's. but outcome needs to be as close to n as possible.

Comment: @Jdweng That is one possible solution, five 10's , I am not looking for the largest number of cuts - I am looking for all possible combinations of cuts <= n (as close to n as possible) .

Comment: @CaptainWibble Looking at your equation - makes it seem fairly simple iterative process which means my remainder of the equation must also be included where  n - (a+b+c) < 8 (would this be correct logic?)

Comment: The scope is not too wide, a brute solution might be acceptable. Otherwise this is typically the kind of problem a solver would ... solve (Microsoft Solver Foundation for instance).

Comment: I know.   You simply count to the max value and test to make sure none exceeds 50 ft.  For example five two's (22222) is less than six zeroes but is 5*12 =60 ft which you would skip.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Microsoft Solver Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/ff713958(v=vs.93)):

```
const int rodLength = 50;
const int lengthA = 8, lengthB = 10, lengthC = 12;

var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
var model = solver.CreateModel();

var decisionA = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "A");
model.AddDecision(decisionA);

var decisionB = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "B");
model.AddDecision(decisionB);

var decisionC = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "C");
model.AddDecision(decisionC);

model.AddGoal("Goal", GoalKind.Minimize,
    rodLength - (decisionA * lengthA) - (decisionB * lengthB) - (decisionC * lengthC));

int maxItems = (rodLength / new [] { lengthA, lengthB, lengthC }.Min());
model.AddConstraint("MaxItems", decisionA + decisionB + decisionC < maxItems);

var solution = solver.Solve();
Console.WriteLine("A " + decisionA.GetDouble());
Console.WriteLine("B " + decisionB.GetDouble());
Console.WriteLine("C " + decisionC.GetDouble());
```

where we trying to minimize the difference between the rod length and the sum of the items constraining the number of items (in your case max 50 / 8 = 6 items).

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample of code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication104
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string max = "111111";
            int size = 50;
            List<List<int>> numbers = CountModThree(max,size);
            Print(numbers);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        static List<List<int>> CountModThree(string max,int size)
        {
            List<List<int>> results = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> newMod3 = new List<int>() {0};
            while(true)
            {
                int length = newMod3.Select(x => x == 0 ? 8 : x == 1 ? 10 : 12).Sum();
                if (length <= size) results.Add(newMod3);
                if (string.Join("", newMod3) == max) break;

                newMod3 = AddOne(newMod3);
            }
            return results;
        }
        static List<int> AddOne(List<int> number)
        {
            List<int> newNumber = new List<int>();
            newNumber.AddRange(number);

            int carry = 1;
            for (int i = number.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int digit = newNumber[i] + carry;
                if (digit == 3)
                {
                    newNumber[i] = 0;
                    carry = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    newNumber[i] = digit;
                    carry = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (carry == 1) newNumber.Insert(0, 0);
            return newNumber;
        }
        static void Print(List<List<int>> numbers)
        {
            foreach(List<int> number in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string : '{0}', Total Length : '{1}, Number 8ft sections : '{2}', Number 10ft sections : '{3}', Number 12ft sections : '{4}'",
                    string.Join("", number),
                    number.Select(x => x == 0 ? 8 : x == 1 ? 10 : 12).Sum(),
                    number.Where(x => x == 0).Count(),
                    number.Where(x => x == 1).Count(),
                    number.Where(x => x == 2).Count()
                    );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking at it .. and have placed it in to my testapplication

Answer (score -1):

You want to get all partitions of n into predefined integer pieces. Simple approach is using recursion.

Python code gives all possible solutions, ignoring summands order due to `last` index usage. So  `8 8 8 8 8 10` and `8 8 10 8 8 8` variants are considered the same. If you need to distinguish them, just remove `last` argument and start loop from 0.

```
def solution(sum, lst, last, sol):
    if sum == 0:
        print(sol)
        return
    for i in range(last, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] <= sum:
            solution(sum - lst[i], lst, i, sol + " " + str(lst[i]))
    return

solution(50, [8,10,12], 0, "")

 8 8 8 8 8 10
 8 8 10 12 12
 8 10 10 10 12
 10 10 10 10 10
```

If you need also solutions with smaller overall length (if n is unreachable) - remember solutions with small rest of sum, then use ones with the smallest rest. Quick-made example:

```
dict = [[]  for i in range(10)]

def solution(sum, lst, last, sol):
    if sum == 0:
        print(sol)
        return
    if sum < 10:
        dict[sum].append(sol)
    for i in range(last, len(lst)):
        if lst[i] <= sum:
            solution(sum - lst[i], lst, i, sol + " " + str(lst[i]))
    return

solution(50, [5, 13 , 21], 0, "")
for i in range(1, len(dict)):
    if len(dict[i]) > 0:
        print(dict[i])
        break

  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5  #exact
  [' 5 5 5 13 21', ' 5 5 13 13 13']  #inexact but close
```

There is also non-recursive method: make table `A[0..n]` and fill it with items (note that table might be huge!)

```
def tablecuts(sum, lst):
    cuts = [[]  for i in range(sum+1)]
    cuts[0].append('*')
    for item in lst:
        for i in range(0, sum - item + 1):
            if len(cuts[i]) > 0:
                for j in cuts[i]:
                    cuts[i+item].append(j+" " + str(item))
    for i in range(len(cuts)):
         print(i, cuts[i])

tablecuts(13, [2,5,7])

0 ['*']
1 []
2 ['* 2']
3 []
4 ['* 2 2']
5 ['* 5']
6 ['* 2 2 2']
7 ['* 2 5', '* 7']
8 ['* 2 2 2 2']
9 ['* 2 2 5', '* 2 7']
10 ['* 2 2 2 2 2', '* 5 5']
11 ['* 2 2 2 5', '* 2 2 7']
12 ['* 2 2 2 2 2 2', '* 2 5 5', '* 5 7']
13 ['* 2 2 2 2 5', '* 2 2 2 7']
```