# Get permutation of a 2 Dimension array Matrix with trio state

Tags: c#

I want to get the permutation of a 2D array with the following condition.

1. the matrix has the same length and width of n element.
2. the value of each element can either be 1 or 0.
3. The value of i-th row and i-th column must 0. The others can be 0 or 1.
4. If i represents the row number and j represents the column number. matrix[i, j] and matrix [j, i] can  be either one value is 0 and another is 1, or both are 0. for example, for matrix[1, 2] and matrix[2, 1]. there are only three possibility of combination.

matrix[1, 2] = 0, matrix[2, 1] = 0

matrix[1, 2] = 0, matrix[2, 1] = 1

matrix[1, 2] = 1, matrix[2, 1] = 0

If n = 3, it should have the following combination.

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 1 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 1 1
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 1 1
0 0 1
0 0 0

0 0 0
1 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 0

0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0

0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0

0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0

0 1 0
0 0 0
1 1 0

0 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 0

0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0

How can I write the code to get the permutation of this n sized Matrix?
There is no need to display the result, you can just get the permutation.

Comment: How do you think you would solve the problem, what have you tried, what didnt it work? i mean surely you have an idea

Comment: @Michael Randall I am still thinking this question. No solution at the moment.

Comment: You really need to put a better example, and explain what you want a little better. i mean someone should be able to come here and see what you mean instantly. Can you put your inputs and outputs, and a bit more explanation

Comment: @paddywide - Please provide sample inputs (several) with the associated outputs - all as valid C# code. Then provide as much code as you can that transforms from the input to the output(s). And then we can help. Right now this is too much like hard work for me to even think about. If it's easy to answer then you get good answers.

Comment: I counted in mod 3 in answer a few weeks ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101245/optimum-cutting-of-rod-with-length-n-into-any-of-3-possibly-4-sizes/55102083#55102083